# nslookup command in loop, only executes once in Linux Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, nslookup

In the following script block, I attempt to execute an nslookup on each fqdn being read from a file.  However, the script stops after executing the first nslookup command.  Code:

```
for HOST in `cat ./rhel_hosts`
do
       echo;
       echo "EXECUTING ==> nslookup ${HOST}"
       CMD="nslookup ${HOST}"       
       exec $CMD
done
```

Any idea why there is no subsequent execution of the nslookup command?

Comment: `exec` stops your shell from running.

Comment: BTW, note that all-caps variables are in reserved space. Using lowercase names for variables you define yourself will stop you from accidentally overwriting things that are meaningful to the shell.

Comment: See [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) re: best practices for iterating over a file line-by-line in bash. Using it, this would look more like `while IFS= read -r line; do printf '%s\n' '' "EXECUTING ==> nslookup $line"; nslookup "$line"; done <./rhel_hosts`

Comment: Why do you need to put the command into a variable in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
exec $CMD
```

with just

```
$CMD
```

The `exec` command replaces the shell process with the program that you execute, instead of running it in a child process. The loop ends because the shell script is no longer being executed in the process.

Comment: Mind, `$CMD` isn't a great idea either. It'd be better with just `nslookup "$HOST"` with no `CMD` variable at all.

Comment: Indeed, but maybe there's more to the script that makes using a dynamic command necessary.

Comment: Maybe, but if that were true, one of the approaches taught in [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) would be a better choice.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I have a feeling that what he really wants is `eval`.

Comment: Quite possibly, but if the answer is eval, chances are good one is asking the wrong question.